# Incorrect statement about biholomorphism between simply connected set and open ball

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm working on a qual problem that asks to fix an incorrect statement and prove the corrected version:

> Let $\Omega$ be a simply connected set and $x \in \Omega$. There exists a unique $r$ and biholomorphism $f: \Omega \rightarrow B(0,r)$ so that $f(x) = 0$ and $f'(x) = 1$.

By the Riemann mapping theorem, there exists a biholomorphism $g: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ to the unit disk so that $g(x) = 0$. I know that $g$ is unique up the argument of $g'(x)$. If I consider the scaled map $f(z) = \frac{g(z)}{g'(x)}$, then $f$ is a biholomorphism between $\Omega$ and $B(0, \frac{1}{|g'(x)|})$ such that $f(x) = 0$ and $f'(x) = 1$. I feel that the contradiction appears somewhere here because $|g'(x)|$ may change depending on what argument we choose for $g'(x)$. If I can somehow show this variation in $|g'(x)|$, then that should contradict the uniqueness of $f$. However, I'm not sure how to proceed with this step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of crucial errors in the statement that must be changed. Firstly, recall that we must have $\Omega \neq \mathbb{C}$ or by Liouville such a biholomorphism must be necessarily constant. Secondly, being a simply connected set is not sufficient to apply the Riemann mapping theorem. For example, there is no such biholomorphism from the closed disc to the open disc. We need that $\Omega$ is an open simply connected set that is not all of $\mathbb{C}$, a simply connected domain.

There are a number of different formulations of the uniqueness claim of the RMT but the most common that you are likely to have seen is to require $f(x) = 0$ and that $f'(x) >0$ is real and positive.

To prove the version you have stated, by the RMT, note that there is a unique biholomorphism from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{D}$ with $g(x) = 0$ and $g'(x) >0$. then let $M = g'(x)$. Consider a scaling of this map by the factor
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{M}g(x)$$
such that $f'(x) = 1$. This map is a biholomorphism fitting your requirements, and clearly multiplying by $1/M$ preserves the uniqueness so $f$ is unique with $r = 1/M$.

**Edit**
I have interchanged the notation of $f$ and $g$ to align with that of your formulation and of the question, apologies for any confusion.